# Masked UIView contents showing when app loads from Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, quartz-core

I have part of a UIView that I added a mask to using:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];

    self.myView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

My problem is, when I return to the app after pressing the home button, the masked area is briefly displayed as the app animates from the background state.

From what I understand, this is because iOS captures an image of the state of your app to display this animation and the masked layer doesn't get captured? (I've had this problem before in programatically capturing a snapshot of my app)

Is there a better place where I could carry out the mask, or perhaps a better method of masking to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

When app come from background it will call following method of AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

**Solution**

- Add layer animation code in above method (applicationWillEnterForeground).
  **OR**
- Add selector or NSNotificationCenter which will call your animation method.

This will work for any view controller of app, if you want it for perticular view check current visible view controller.